# XCUI Test hold the finger on the screen

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing

Is it possible with XCUI test or any framework, that the UI test put down the 'finger' to the screen, then hold it, while change its coordinates a few times, then release it.

Answer (score 1):

You want [`pressForDuration:thenDragToElement:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xcuielement/1618670-pressforduration) on XCUIElement.

```
let app = XCUIApplication
let button = app.buttons["myButton"]
let text = app.staticTexts["myText"]
button.pressForDuration(2, thenDragToElement: text)
```

This method can be used on any XCUIElement, not just buttons and texts.

Comment: Thank you, I am searching something like that, but I have to change the coordinates more than one time. Sorry for not being accurate enough, edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

It can not be done in XCUI with public API.

---

I think it would be extremely difficult. There is a private API in `XCTest` in `XCEventGenerator`, it might do what you need.

`- (void)_startEventSequenceWithSteppingCallback:(CDUnknownBlockType)arg1;`

I have no idea what it is. How `XCEventGenerator` can be used: https://github.com/avito-tech/Mixbox/blob/e590de08d5883ee3e1adedcd389c285f80db7101/Frameworks/XcuiDriver/PrivateHeaders/SwiftWrapper/EventGenerator.swift

To implement it you need to include private headers in your project, use wrapper, you may need to use disassembler, debugging skills, knowing how to reverse engineer things in runtime. And it would be guaranteed.

---

Also it is definitely possible inside the application using private API of IOKit. Example: https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/blob/91c27bb8a15e723df974f620f7f576a30a6a7484/EarlGrey/Event/GREYTouchInjector.h

You can simulate every gesture inside app, that is also required a lot of work and also IPC between test runner and app if you are using XCUI. But it also has downside: if anything will be displayed above your application (e.g.: system alert), your gesture will not affect it, so would be a little far from black box testing.